# How to traverse through variable length paths to same destination?

Tags: python, breadth-first-search, network-analysis

I have a directed network as follows.

[image]

Now, I would like to get all the possible 4 length and 5 length paths of this graph (where both the starting and ending paths are B)

Examples of 4 length paths are;

- B--C--B--A--B
- B--A--B--B--B
- B--A--B--C--B

Examples of 5 length paths are;

- B--C--B--A--B--B
- B--A--B--B--C--B

I tried to use Breadth First Search (BFS) to solve this. It seems like most of the code of BFS algorithm does not satisfies my requirements. That is;

- They do not consider variable length paths
- Their starting and end node is not same as mine (They are different)

My current code is as follows:

```
graph = {'A': ['B'],
         'B': ['A','C', 'B'],
         'C': ['B']}

# visits all the nodes of a graph (connected component) using BFS
def bfs_connected_component(graph, start):
   # keep track of all visited nodes
   explored = []
   # keep track of nodes to be checked
   queue = [start]

   # keep looping until there are nodes still to be checked
   while queue:
       # pop shallowest node (first node) from queue
       node = queue.pop(0)
       if node not in explored:
           # add node to list of checked nodes
           explored.append(node)
           neighbours = graph[node]

           # add neighbours of node to queue
           for neighbour in neighbours:
               queue.append(neighbour)
   return explored

bfs_connected_component(graph,'A')
```

I would like to know if there are any python libraries I can use for this or is there is a way to modify BFS to accomplish this problem.

I am happy to provide more examples if needed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When searching for all combinatorial results, I found that recursive generators in python provide more compact and understandable code compared to other approaches (such as recursive functions, or stack-based equivalents).

Here we are looking for all paths from `node` to `goal` of fixed `length`. The list `path` is used as an accumulator, which, at the base case, becomes a prefix of the 1-path passing thru `node`.

```
def all_paths(graph, node, goal, length, path=[]):
    if length == 0 and node == goal:
        yield path + [node]
    elif length > 0:
        for n in graph[node]:
            yield from all_paths(graph, n, goal, length - 1, path + [node])
```

Paths of length 4:

```
>>> print(*all_paths(graph, 'B', 'B', 4), sep='\n')
['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B']
['B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B']
['B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

Paths of length 5:

```
>>> print(*all_paths(graph, 'B', 'B', 5), sep='\n')
['B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B']
['B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B']
['B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'B']
['B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. very helpful :)

Comment: If I need to change my starting and end node as A, I hope the only changes I need to do are 1) the `node` and `goal` parameters when calling the function as A, A and; 2) the if condition as `if length == 0 and node == 'A':`

Comment: I had a small error in the first line, which should read as `if length == 0 and node == goal:`, so you need to change only the arguments passed to the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot once again :)